# what is the difference between data file and data block in oracle

Tags: oracle, storage

I'd like to know if there is any difference between the data block which is the  smallest logical unit of data storage in Oracle Database and the data file which is a physical file on disk that was created by Oracle Database and contains the data for a database?

Can anybody please tell me that what exactly difference between the data file and the data block?

Comment: A data file contains many, many data blocks

Comment: I usually don't link answers like "read the documentation" but in this case this is the only answer I have.

Comment: Weird question. So, you're asking what is the difference between a logical and a physical component (which you mention yourself already). One is logical, the other is physical. Please rephrase your question to a serious question, if you want a serious answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Logical Storage Structures section in the [Oracle Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/E41396-12.pdf) has a good explanation of both data blocks and data files (pages 259 - 296).  There is quite a bit of good information including illustrations, but here are some excerpts:

> **data block** 
>   Smallest logical unit of data storage in Oracle Database.
>   Other names for data blocks include Oracle blocks or pages. One data
>   block corresponds to a specific number of bytes of physical space on
>   disk.
>
> **data file**
>   A physical file on disk that was created by Oracle Database
>   and contains the data for a database. The data files can be located
>   either in an operating system file system or Oracle ASM disk group.

Comment: I think this link to the manual is better: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/logical.htm#CNCPT004

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Both my link and yours point to the 12c Concepts Guide.  The difference is that mine is to the pdf and yours is to the web documentation - each useful depending on how it needs to be consumed.